# Compiling with TCC on Cygwin

Tags: c, terminal, cygwin, printf, fgets

I was testing a very basic program written in C, the entirety of which is enclosed below. Upon attempting to execute the executable produced by TCC, I noticed that I was required to enter input for each successive fgets() prior to actually seeing output from any printf() calls.

This was very confusing, so I decided to try running the executable on the standard Windows console. It ran flawlessly, and input and output prompts were shown in the proper order.

However, I noticed that if I compiled the program with GCC it would work fine on the terminal compiled in Cygwin (mintty, though I got the same results with rxvt).

Could anyone give an explanation as to why this is happening, and how I can stop it from happening? I'd like to compile my programs independent of Cygwin while still using a Cygwin-based terminal.

Thanks!

```
int main()
{
        char something[12];

        printf("This printf() should be outputted before you are prompted for input: ");

        fgets(something, sizeof something, stdin);

        printf("You entered, %s", something);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mintty and rxvt are terminal emulators based on Unix [pseudo terminal devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal). Cygwin implements these based on [Windows pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365780.aspx).

When you compile a program with Cygwin gcc, it gets linked to the Cygwin DLL, which contains all the magic for making streams connected to a terminal work as they should on a Unix system, which means line buffering by default.

However, when you compile the program with tcc, you create a native Windows program, and that only sees the underlying Windows pipes. In the Microsoft C library, streams connected to pipes are fully buffered by default, which is why flushing explicitly with `fflush(stdout)` or disabling the buffering with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` helps. MS's C library does not support line buffering.

Comment: Of all the answers, I thought this one had the most thorough explanation, which is why I selected it as the "Best" answer. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This is down to the buffering of standard input and standard output. I'm not sure what the C standard has to say about this (in C++ the streams are tied by default), but you can flush standard output yourself with :

```
 fflush( stdout );
```

after the call to printf.

Answer (score 1):

The standard output stream is usually line-buffered, i.e. the buffer gets flushed when you print a newline.

You may flush it explicitly with:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

And you can turn off buffering for a given stream `s` with:

```
setvbuf(s, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

See the [manpage of setvbuf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) for more details.

Comment: The default is that stdout is line buffered when sent to a terminal, and fully buffered when sent to something else (pipe, socket, file, etc.) By comparison, stderr is unbuffered by default (since it's used to write information that can diagnose why a crash is happening, potentially before buffers are auto-flushed).

Comment: @Donal Yep, that's what the standard says, and it's also what Cygwin implements, but not the Microsoft C library. There, both stdout and stderr are unbuffered when connected to a console, and  fully buffered when connected to a file or pipe. Line buffering is not supported.

Comment: @ak2: That's why I wasn't offering it as a solution. MS fluffing _yet another_ part of the C library is hardly surprising…